# Need Help In Recursive WITH SQL statement

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression

With reference to CDB$ROOT in Oracle 18c Express Edition

How to complete the following task using a Recursive WITH SQL statement?

For each user who is granted the “CREATE SESSION" (directly, granted roles with the
permission, or granted role(s) which is assigned roles with permission, and so on), display the
USERNAME and the ACCOUNT_STATUS of that user. The output should be sorted by
username.

Comment: What's recursive about it?

Comment: @alfasin: because the privilege could be granted to a role that contains a role that contains a role that contains the privilege

Comment: [Something like this](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/recursively_list_privilege.html) should get you started; it's a hierarchical approach rather than a recursive CTE but that may be OK for you, and if not you can convert it?

Comment: Sounds suspciously like a homework assignment.  And I'm sure I responded to the same question a few days ago, though I can't find it now.  Pete Finnigan has already written a script that does exactly what you describe.  There's your clue.  Google is your friend.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for the information, i solved the question already:)